# Hot reload for tomcat server via docker

Tags: java, docker, tomcat

I have a sample Tomcat / Jax-RS application, where I want to implement,ent hot-reload / hot-swap using docker.

I have created my docker file like this:

```
FROM tomcat:8.0-jre8-alpine
ENV JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=9999,server=y,suspend=n
ADD target/*.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps

EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 9999

CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

This starts up the tomcat server correctly and I can access my sample JAX-RS endpoint.

The intention is, that I can change something in the endpoint, and it would update automatically.

I have attached a remote debugger using IntelliJ to connect to my docker instance using the following configuration as displayed in the image below.

[image]

However, when anything in the codebase is updated, it does not update anything automatically, even though the debugger is attached correctly, and gives the following response:

`Connected to the target VM, address: '172.17.0.2:9999', transport: 'socket'`